# Using fetch() in browser is converting http to https

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch-api

I am making an http call to a URL in chrome browser console but it is automatically converting my call to https. Due to this I am getting connection time out error. Following is the code to give a better insight:

```
fetch(`http://someurl.com`, {
        method: "POST",
        mode: "cors",
        referrer:"unsafe-url",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'} ,
        body: {data:["g@g.com"]}
}).then(res => {
        console.log('result is:',res);
}).catch(err=> {
        console.log('error is:',err)
});
```

However, the call is getting made to "https://someurl.com" instead, which does not exist. Therefore, I am getting the error:

```
POST https://someurl.com net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check your HSTS Cache. Does this happen in a new private/incognito window?

Comment: I just checked, doing it in incognito is giving me 
Mixed Content: The page at 'xxx' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://someurl.com/'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: That's by-design. You need to be using `https://` **everywhere**. If you have a dependency on a non-HTTPS external service then you'll need to complain to them to fix it: there's no way around browser restrictions like that: https://dev.to/mittalyashu/mixed-content-fetching-data-from-https-and-http-3n31

Comment: Actually I am trying out a side project that is deployed in aws. So the url is http. Is there any workaround that i can do?

Comment: AWS offers HTTPS for all endpoints. **Exactly** what AWS service/platform are you using and what problems are you having getting HTTPS to work?

Comment: That is a bummer. I was creating a chrome extension that was making an http call to aws instance. I have deployed a code on ec2 instance. I am accessing it via this http request

Comment: What are you referring to when you say "That is a bummer"? As I said, setting up HTTPS in AWS is easy, so I don't understand what you seem unhappy about.

Comment: I will try setting up https endpoints for the request

Comment: You either have a <meta> in the doc or an HTTP header for the doc's response setting the CSP "upgrade-insecure-requests". No way around apart downgrading your CSP..